# wp_enqueue_style() won't go away

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I set up a child theme and enqueued the style.css file from the parent first, then I enqueued it from the child theme.

Everything is working fine!

All I wanted to do was disable the call to the child stylesheet, so I deleted the wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',...) bit of code from the function and saved the file.

However, everytime I reload the pages the child theme style is still being called.  I have stopped and started the server, but to no avail.

I am using XAMPP and I think there is some kind of server side caching going on, but I am not sure how to get it to update and refresh the function and not call the child stylesheet.

Any suggestions?

I tried renaming my function and only including the parent style like this:

```
function worker401k_enqueue_parent_styles() {
    $parent_style = get_template_directory_uri();
    // Enque the Parent styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style',
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
      wp_get_theme()->get('Version'),
      'screen'
    );
}
// The third parameter is the priority
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'worker401k_enqueue_parent_styles', 10 );
```

I expected the call to go away, but no, it is still there!!

http://localhost/wp_1/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen-child/style.css?ver=0.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: Are you sure that there is not any other wp_enqueue_scripts action on your theme? If you don't find in your child theme, take a look in the parent theme.

Comment: I just realized that this was a stupid question. 
It is required to have style.css to even have a child theme.   It wouldn't matter what I did when I enqueue the parent file.  Now I just have to figure out how I can enqueue another css file.